# Where is the sunbeam on kingdom rush?

Tags: achievements, kingdom-rush

There is an achievement to "fire the sunbeam" 20 times.

Where is the sunbeam and how do I fire it?

Comment: Haven't played this in awhile, I do know it's somewhere on one of the later stages as part of the map itself. Not something you can buy and place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the achievement titled 'Sunburner!' - this requires you to fire 'The Sunray' twenty times. The Sunray is a map-specific special tower located on Level 9 ('Stormcloud Temple') It initially cannot be fired, however for 100 gold you can add a Sunray Sorcerer that allows it to fire for 75-125 damage with a charge time of 19 seconds. You can purchase up to 4 sorcerers for the temple, allowing it a total of 225-275 damage with a 10-second charge time.

It does not automatically attack enemies - once it is ready, you must manually click on it and target a location.

*Source:* [Kingdom Rush Wiki - Sunray Tower](http://kingdomrushtd.wikia.com/wiki/Sunray_Tower)

Comment: How does it work on the Android version? How can you get the `Sunray Sorcerer`

Comment: @Nameiscarl According to the same page, the Sunray Tower cannot be used on the iOS and Android versions due to high resource demands.